# Android Ant build using ${sdk.dir} in project.properties

Tags: android, ant

I want to use the `${sdk.dir}` variable in my project.properties file, so I can check this into version control and use the same file on different setup machines.

My working setup looks like this:

My **project.properties**:

```
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=..\\..\\..\\sdk\\extras\\android\\support\\v7\\appcompat
android.library.reference.2=..\\..\\..\\sdk\\extras\\google\\google_play_services\\libproject\\google-play-services_lib
```

My **local.properties**:

```
sdk.dir=C:\\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\\sdk
```

this setup compiles with ant from the command line. but when I replace the `..\\..\\..\\`with `${sdk.dir}` I get the error:

**project.properties** how I want it to use:

```
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=${sdk.dir}\\extras\\android\\support\\v7\\appcompat
android.library.reference.2=${sdk.dir}\\extras\\google\\google_play_services\\libproject\\google-play-services_lib
```

results in:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:460:
Failed to resolve library path:
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
```

so the variable `${sdk.dir}` is replaced correctly but somehow it cannot be resolved. Any ideas?

**update Edit**

Using the Variable for the proGuard setup in the same file (`project.properties`) is working fine what so ever:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: no. It is just working with the absolut path.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve your issue, *per se*, but I hope it will help you.

My issue was that I needed to reference the Google Play Services SDK as a library in my project. However, our app is built automatically on a separate box using Ant.

I found that library projects cannot be referenced using absolute paths; they must be relative to your project, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#considerations):

> ### Library project storage location
>
> There are no specific requirements on where you should store a library project, relative to a dependent application project, as long as the application project can reference the library project by a relative link. What is important is that the main project can reference the library project through a relative link.

I used the `ant.properties` file to set the `android.library.reference.1=../../../../Program Files/Android/android-sdk/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` library. This reference is solely for the build server and this path is relative to the library location on the build server.

For development, I use Eclipse. So, the library's relative path is referenced using the `project.properties` file and is relative to my development box. This means that whenever I trigger a build on the server (which uses Ant), the reference in the `ant.properties` is used as opposed to the `project.properties` file.

The `ant.properties` file is lower level and therefore will override anything written in the `project.properties`/`local.properties` files.

As you can see this is not the answer I am sure you're looking for, but it is a limitation of Ant. My final bit of advice is that you move away from Ant and use [Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-projects).